# Getting message A stop job is running advanced key-value store no limit

Tags: ubuntu, redis

I am using ubuntu OS. when  I started my system I am seeing  a message " A stop job is running advanced key-value store no limit".
My Laptop screen is stuck not able to do anything.
Can anyone help  me How to fix this.

Comment: have you tried any of the myriad solutions you get when searching the web for `A stop job is running advanced key-value store no limit` - you'll get better results using `advanced` rather than `adanced`

Comment: @JaromandaX It was typo, I have updated that. I searched a lot but I haven't got anything. I am getting solution that I have run some commands but My screen is stuck in that message so can't  run commands.

Comment: Oh, so you can't even switch to a different console? ctrl+alt+F1 or Ctrl+alt+f2 etc?

Comment: no @JaromandaX not able to perform any action.

Comment: does ubuntu have a recovery mode boot option?